# How to store default entered value in custom field of quantity on Hand.?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

Need to store default value on qty in M.sqr and square meter like quantity on hand showing default entered value.

when i click on update button of quantity on Hand from product inventory page
then it should show me a previous entered value.

class stock_change_product_qty(osv.osv):

```
_inherit = 'stock.change.product.qty'
_columns = {
    'new_quantity' : fields.float('Qty in Boxes'),
    'squ_meter': fields.related('product_id','squ_meter', type='float', relation='product.product', string='Square Meter'),
    'qty_char': fields.float('Qty in M.sqr', compute='_compute_qty_char'),

}

@api.depends('new_quantity', 'squ_meter')
def _compute_qty_char(self):
    for record in self:
        record.qty_char = record.new_quantity * record.squ_meter
```

view.xml

```
        <field name="name">update_product_quantity inherit</field>
        <field name="model">stock.change.product.qty</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_change_product_quantity"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//field[@name='new_quantity']"  position="attributes">
                <attribute name="string">Qty in Boxes</attribute>
            </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='new_quantity']"  position="replace">

                <field name="new_quantity"/>
                <field name="squ_meter"/>
                <field name="qty_char"/>

            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use a function as default value for your field:

**odoo V8**

```python
from openerp import api, fields, models

class stock_change_product_qty(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'stock.change.product.qty'

     new_quantity = fields.Float(string='Qty in Boxes', default=1.0),
     squ_meter = fields.Float(related='product_id.squ_meter', string='Square Meter', default=1.0),
     qty_char = fields.Float('Qty in M.sqr', compute='_compute_qty_char'),

      }

    @api.one
    @api.depends('new_quantity', 'squ_meter')
    def _compute_qty_char(self):
        for record in self:
            record.qty_char = record.new_quantity * record.squ_meter
```

**odoo V7**

```
def _your_function(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    your code here
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return field_value

_defaults = {
    'your_field' : _your_function,
    }
```

**@api.onchange**

This decorator will trigger the call to the decorated function if any of the fields specified in the decorator is changed in the form:

```
@api.onchange('fieldx')
def do_stuff(self):
    if self.fieldx == x:
        self.fieldy = 'toto'
```

In previous sample self corresponds to the record currently edited on the form. When in on_change context all work is done in the cache. So you can alter RecordSet inside your function without being worried about altering database. That’s the main difference with @api.depends

At function return, differences between the cache and the RecordSet will be returned to the form.

Comment: Hey jainik  can u pls explain me by giving some code cause i used this solution its giving me an error of TypeError: _compute_qty_char() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)

Comment: thanks jainik but one issue is still remain is that quantity on hand's value showing me in my custom field which i don't need it  my need is that i've already field of quantity on Hand when i'm entering any values in this field at that time another custom field which i have is square meter so this fields value get multiplied to quantity on Hand field after this whatever the value comes it displaying in my another custom field that is qty_char and that value i need to get remain stored unless and until i don't change pls help me

Comment: so you can use @api.onchange on squ_meter and new_quantity

Comment: like what                                                                                                 now you can have look on above image what actually i need

Comment: Thanks a lot jainik it really helped me